# Breadcrumb apps for when you get lost

Tags: apps, metering, location-services

Is there any kind of breadcrumb application available out there? Probably I don't know synonyms for this and that's why I can't find one..

I essentially need to trace me back in a large unknown town or in the forest or whatever.

Since the phone has a GPS receiver and it can record steps periodically it could record my path and play it back for me if I get lost and need to go back.

Any ideas? Or am I on my own to build one?

Comment: GMaps has this track feature with Latitude capabilities but is far from what you need. About the GPS tag, it is because there isn't a feature with only GPS in Windows Phone. It's always location services, that uses cellular antennas and WiFi to locate you. GPS is part of it and you can't use separately.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few apps out there, including [Simple OSM](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=9710865b-2c38-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) which will show your track on a map as you move (it'll also show paths if they're known, should you want a shortcut back :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an app that will track your every step for replaying, but something you might find helpful is the Base app included in [Jack of Tools Pro](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/jack-of-tools-pro/62b13259-c06a-4f24-a95c-dd904235beb1). It allows you to log a location and then it can later point you in the direction (as the crow flies) you need to go to get back to it. It won't tell you exactly which streets you need to turn on along your route, but it should generally be enough to help you find your way back if you're on foot. Even if you decide this doesn't suit your needs, there are a *lot* of other handy utilities in Jack of Tools Pro - I consider it more than worth the $1.99 USD.

Another option is to just save whatever location you want to return to in your Maps app, and then ask for return directions later. Again, this won't necessarily take you back along the path you've walked but it should be enough to get you un-lost. Do bear in mind though that most Maps apps do rely on streets to get you where you're going - they probably won't be so useful in the woods as something more rudimentary, like Base, might be.

Answer (score 0):

There are several GPS-based apps for Windows phones. You can not only use them for location tracking purposes but also as a [find my phone](https://www.gadgetdetected.com/2017/04/find-my-phone/) alternative app. Here are some, Here Drive+, GMaps, Haze, etc..